# Is class is Algabraic Data Type?

Tags: class, types, algebraic-data-types

I am reading about Algabraic Data Types. All articles writes about them as about container that can include others types. And it's seems for me similar that class do. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming when you say "class" it refers classes from object oriented programming paradigm.

The answer is No.

Class is a template for creating objects. Objects have both behavior and state.
Algebraic data types are more like union and product types. They do maintain state,
but they do not have any behavior. ADT's do not have methods if you compare them to objects.

You can however simulate the ADT's using objects and objects using ADT's (given you have support for existential data types)

Answer (score 0):

"Support of algebraic data types" means ability to combine any given types `A` and `B` in tuples `(A, B)` (product types) and disjoint unions `A | B` (sum types).

Almost every modern language supports product types one way or another. You can think of classes as product types.

But the concept of sum types is somewhat hostile to object oriented way of modelling things (where classes come from).

Comment: `sum types is somewhat hostile to object oriented way of modelling things ` Why do you say hostile, could you please elaborate?

Comment: Both sum types and inheritance are ways to model `is a` relation between concepts. 
`Animal = Cat | Dog` or `class Cat extend Animal; class Dog extends Animal`.
With sum types you are able to enumerate all variants. With inheritance you can't. OOP approach teaches that `Animal` should be open for extension with new variants and one shouldn't try to enumerate them all. Mainstream OOP language for decades haven't been providing a convenient way to model sum types. The closest thing in OOP that workarounds it  is Visitor pattern.